# How to get array with html same name classes in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I couldn't find something I need. So my problem is that I have 4 inputs in HTML with the same name and I want to make an array with them in PHP. Is there any way to do this? View a picture below: [Photo of 4 inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg4zz.png)

So these 4 inputs have same name and I want to get information which user typed in and insert it into HTML page, Please answer my question or recommend a better way to do this!

Here is my code:

```html
   <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="Some text here"/>
   <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="Some text here"/>
   <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="Some text here"/>
   <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="Some text here"/>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit right now

Comment: You don't have a `name` attribute in this inputs

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control" name="text[]" placeholder="Some text here" />
       <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control"  name="text[]"  placeholder="Some text here"/>
       <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control" name="text[]"  placeholder="Some text here"/>
       <input class="inputText" type = "text" class="form-control"  name="text[]"  placeholder="Some text here"/>
```

then you will get the "name" array in your php file when you print $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a name in your input, so you'll never get the value in your $_POST :). So, we add names:

```
<input name="thing1" value="1" />
<input name="thing2" value="2" />
<input name="thing3" value="3" />
<input name="thing4" value="4" />
```

Now you can use `$_POST['thing1']` to `$_POST['thing4']`. But we want them in an array, so they need to be the same name.

```
<input name="thing" value="1" />
<input name="thing" value="2" />
```

Unfortunally, you now have one value in `$_POST['thing']`, which is `'2'` (the last overwrites the previous). In order to tell PHP/html to make it an array, you can use the same trick as you'd use in PHP :

```
<input name="thing[]" value="1" />
<input name="thing[]" value="2" />
<input name="thing[]" value="3" />
<input name="thing[]" value="4" />
```

And you you have `$_POST['thing']` with the value `['1','2','3','4']`